# debian dpkg-dist files after apt upgrade

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

When upgrading packages in Debian, often when files were edited, the package manager creates extra files as in:

```
/etc/default/grub.dpkg-dist  
/etc/mysql/my.cnf.dpkg-dist
```

More rarely, those files can create problems when upgrading production servers.

I do not feel that is a particular good solution deleting them by hand or using scripts. Is there any `dpkg` configuration where their creation can be forbidden?

Answer (score 4):

No, I don't think that there is such an option for `dpkg`. There are several `--force-conf*` options that can change the behaviour of `dpkg` regarding configuration file conflicts. See this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138751/unattended-upgrades-and-modified-configuration-files) and in this [article](https://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/09/21/debian-conffile-configuration-file-managed-by-dpkg/).

But with any option, when there is a config file conflict, it will either

- keep the existing version and add the new version with suffix `.dpkg-dist`, or
- install the new version and keep a backup of the old version with suffix `.dpkg-old`

You could write a post install script to get rid of those files, but I don't think that would be a good idea. When there is a conflict, it is worth looking into what changed.

The files with `.dpkg-*` suffix should not cause any problems. I would assume the problems rather come from changes in the way the new package version interprets the old config file.

Comment: I have had that kind of files creeping up in modules directories where they influence the behaviour of the application.