# conffile prompt during scripted update

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation

I have a script that runs `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y` on a weekly basis across many servers.

When testing this with Debian 9, I've noticed it gets caught with a prompt asking whether to keep my modified configuration file or install the maintainer's version (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`), shown in the screenshot below:
[image: Package configuration...modified configuration file]

**My question is this: What do I need to include in my command so that this does not prompt? The desired behavior is that it would keep the local configuration file and continue with the upgrade.**

I have tried:

- adding `--force-yes` to `apt-get upgrade`
- adding options in line either before the upgrade command or after as I was unsure of order

  ```
  apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" upgrade
  ```
- creating `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/local` with contents:

  ```
  Dpkg::Options {
      "--force-confdef";
      "--force-confold";
  }
  ```
- editing `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.conf` with:

  ```
  force confdef,confold
  ```

Nothing I tried suppressed the prompt and I'm not sure what to try next.

I based a lot of these attempts off of this StackExchange post, [Unattended upgrades and modified configuration files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138751/unattended-upgrades-and-modified-configuration-files), which introduced me to the `unattended-upgrades` package. We don't currently use this, but if it is the proper way to accomplish weekly updates/upgrades on Debian then I'll look into it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting DEBIAN_FRONTEND to non-interactive.  e.g.

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```

See `man 7 debconf` for more details:

> **noninteractive**
>
> This is the anti-frontend. It never interacts with you at all, and
> makes the default answers be used for all questions.  It  might mail
> error messages to root, but that's it; otherwise it is completely
> silent and unobtrusive, a perfect frontend for automatic installs.
>
> If you are using this front-end, and require non-default answers to
> questions, you will need to preseed the debconf database; see the
> section below on **Unattended Package Installation** for more details.